# Получение данных из JSON

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Пытаюсь распарсить JSON. Получаю данные:

```
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:mutableData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
```

Вывожу и вижу такую структуру :

```
{
response =     {
    items =         (
                    {
            created = "Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)";
            to = "sdfs";
            from = "blabla";
            id = 472;
            price = 58;
        }
    );
};
```

}

Нужно извлечь значение элемента "id" , для этого делаю:

```
NSDictionary *response = [res objectForKey:@"response"];
NSDictionary *items = [response objectForKey:@"items"];
NSString *orderID = [items valueForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@"%@",orderID);
```

И в логах получаю такое:

```
(
472   )
```

Т.е. не просто число, а число со скобками, пробелами и переходом на новую строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто: вызывая метод `-valueForKey:` у массива вы получаете **массив**, который формируется следующим образом:

> каждому элементу исходного массива  отправляется сообщение `-valueForKey:`, и результаты записываются в новый массив, который вы и получаете на выходе.

А так как в массиве `items` *(у вас он по ошибке определён как словарь)*  только один элемент, то массив `orderID` *(у вас он по ошибке определён как строка)* содержит только одно значение — `@472`.
Если вы уверены, что длина массива `items` всегда равна 1, то можно просто заменить предпоследнюю строку на:

```
NSString *orderID = [[items valueForKey: @"id"] lastObject];
```

---

1. Документация Apple: NSArray's -valueForKey:
2. szarajewski: [«NS... коллекции и KVC методы доступа»](http://szarajewski.blogspot.ru/2013/03/ns-kvc.html)
3. [«Projections on NSArray using valueForKey:»](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/2011/05/projections-on-nsarray-using-valueforkey)
4. NSHipster: [«KVC Collection Operators»](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/)

Answer (score 1):

Может быть так: NSString * orderID = [items objectForKey:@"id"];

Comment: Не получается, вылетает с ошибкой: [__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16563930...
NSString * orderID = [[items objectForKey:@"id"] stringValue] - тоже не помогает

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *response = [res objectForKey:@"response"];
NSArray *items = [response objectForKey:@"items"];
NSNumber *orderID = [[items lastObject] objectForKey:@"id"];
```